# Fastest way to build evolving Covariance from D x T x N Tensor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, covariance, tensor, estimation

Given are `N` different measurements of a sequence `x1, x2, ..., xT`, where `x` has the dimension `D`. The data is stored in an `D x T x N` Tensor, namly `X`. I would like to build the Tensor `S` with dimensions `D x D x T`, which defines the covariance between the dimensions of `x` for every timestep `t` (`t = 1, ..., T`), as fast as possible. My current approach is a for-loop, which seems to be very slow.

```
clear all; close all; clc; rng(0);

% - test data
D = 2;
T = 10;
N = 100;
X = rand(D,T,N);

% - covariance
tic;
S = zeros(D,D,T);
for i = 1:T
    S(:,:,i) = cov(reshape((X(:,i,:)),D,N)');
end
toc;
```

Comment: You can already simplify your code by rearranging your matrice X, so construct a 100x2x10 matrice instead of a 2x10x100 matrice. (`rand(N,D,T)`). Then reshape become useless and you can simply use `S(:,:,i) = cov((X(:,:,i)));`. By the way, if you want to remove singleton dimension, matlab as a built-in function for that called `squeeze`.

Comment: Also; use `clear;` instead of `clear all;`. It will leave compiled functions in memory and your code will be faster on every one but the first run.